# How can I use an Excel formula (no VBA) to retrieve a piece of data within an HTTP POST response?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, http-post, worksheet-function

Is there any way to craft an Excel hyperlink formula that would send an HTTP POST on click and parse the response to populate another cell?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Sorry, i didn't see "**no vba**" in your title. But i can't see how you would do.

You can do it with vba and find valuable information on these threads:

- [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)
- [Perform HTTP Post from within Excel and Parse Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820345/perform-http-post-from-within-excel-and-parse-results)

Here is a code sample:

```
'Send the request
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
   objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.send ("")

'Get the result
myText = objHTTP.responseText

'Set it in the current cell
ActiveCell.Value = myText
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function HttpPOST(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.send ("")
   myText = objHTTP.responseText
   getHTTP2 = myText

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in excel formula,

## =WEBSERVICE(A2)

[image]

This will populate content of the URL in the cell.