# Excel data import in specific cell

Tags: regex, vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I would like to list up devices and put their prices next to them.

My goal is to check different sites every week and notice trends.

This is a hobby project, I know there are sites that already do this.

For instance:

```
Device    | URL Site 1  | Site 1  | URL Site 2  | Site 2 
Device a  | http://...  | €40,00  | http://...  | €45,00
Device b  | http://...  | €28,00  | http://...  | €30,50
```

Manually, this is a lot of work (checking every week), so I thought a Macro in Excel would help. The thing is, I would like to put the data in a single cell and excel only recognises tables. Solution: view source code, read price, export price to specific cell.

I think this is all possible within Excel, but I can't quiet figure out how to read the price or other given data and how to put it in one specific cell. Can I specify coordinates in the source code, or is there a more effective way of thinking?

Comment: Actually, it's not right question for SO, since you don't provide even a piece of code. Each website has it's own structure, so to suggest some method of retrieving data from the website it's necessary to know at least URL. Generally you can get data from websites via Excel's querytable, automating IE or parsing XHR response. Then you should convert the data to the appropriate form (e. g. array), and put it to the worksheet.

Comment: For instance _[this site](http://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_bosch-wtw-85230-2004975.html)_, line 78 of source code has the price. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Things to get you started: [click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820345/perform-http-post-from-within-excel-and-parse-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to find out how does the website works. For the [page](http://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_bosch-wtw-85230-2004975.html) you asked I have done the following:

- Opened http://www.mediamarkt.de page in Chrome.
- Typed BOSCH WTW 85230 in the search box, suggestion list appeared.
- Pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer tools and clicked Network tab.
- Each time I was typing, the new request appeared (see yellow areas):

[image: search box]

- Clicked the request to examine general info:

[image: general]

You can see that it uses GET method and some parameters including url-encoded product name.

- Clicked the Response tab to examine the data returning from the server:

[image: response]

You can see it is a regular JSON, full content is as follows:

```
{"suggestions":[{"attributes":{"energyefficiencyclass":"A++","modelnumber":"2004975","availabilityindicator":"10","customerrating":"0.00000","ImageUrl":"http://pics.redblue.de/artikelid/DE/2004975/CHECK","collection":"shop","id":"MediaDEdece2358813","currentprice":"444.00","availabilitytext":"Lieferung in 11-12 Werktagen"},"hitCount":0,"image":"http://pics.redblue.de/artikelid/DE/2004975/CHECK","name":"BOSCH WTW 85230 Kondensationstrockner mit Warmepumpentechnologie (8 kg, A++)","priority":9775,"searchParams":"/Search.ff?query=BOSCH+WTW+85230+Kondensationstrockner+mit+W%C3%A4rmepumpentechnologie+%288+kg%2C+A+%2B+%2B+%29\u0026channel=mmdede","type":"productName"}]}
```

Here you can find `"currentprice":"444.00"` property with the price.

- Simplified the request by throwing out some optional parameters, it turned out that the same JSON response can be received by the URL http://www.mediamarkt.de/FACT-Finder/Suggest.ff?channel=mmdede&query=BOSCH+WTW+85230
- That data was enough to built some code, assuming that first column intended for products:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMediaMarkt()

    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim aResult() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sRespText As String

    ' set source range with product names from column A
    Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A3")
    ' create one column array the same size
    ReDim aResult(1 To oRange.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    ' loop rows one by one, make XHR for each product
    For i = 1 To oRange.Rows.Count
        ' build up URL
        sURL = "http://www.mediamarkt.de/FACT-Finder/Suggest.ff?channel=mmdede&query=" & EncodeUriComponent(oRange.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        ' retrieve HTML content
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", sURL, False
            .Send
            sRespText = .responseText
        End With
        ' regular expression for price property
        With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = """currentprice""\:""([\d.]+)""" ' capture digits after 'currentprice' in submatch
            With .Execute(sRespText)
                If .Count = 0 Then ' no matches, something going wrong
                    aResult(i, 1) = "N/A"
                Else ' store the price to the array from the submatch
                    aResult(i, 1) = .Item(0).Submatches(0)
                End If
            End With
        End With
    Next
    ' output resultion array to column B
    Output Sheets(1).Range("B1"), aResult

End Sub

Function EncodeUriComponent(strText)
    Static objHtmlfile As Object
    If objHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set objHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHtmlfile.parentWindow.execScript "function encode(s) {return encodeURIComponent(s)}", "jscript"
    End If
    EncodeUriComponent = objHtmlfile.parentWindow.encode(strText)
End Function

Sub Output(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)
    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
            UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
            UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1 _
        )
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

- Filled worksheet with some product names:

[image: products]

- Launched the sub and got the result:

[image: result]

It is just the example how to retrieve a data from the website via XHR and parse a response with RegExp, I hope it helps.